# Can we keep a common repository for SQLLite in which android apps can do CRUD operations?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am creating an android application. Users will do select, insert, update operations on database. SQLLite is specific to a device(correct me if I am wrong) i.e., local storage. But, I want to maintain a central repository from which all the users will access the data. Can we achieve this with SQLLite? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not really sure if understand you correct, but every database which is created in Android application is a local database and if you want all users to have access to same data you need some Cloud or Web Server

Comment: Hi @MrVasilev, in web server can we use SQLLite as common repository? Will that be possible?

Comment: If you are not familiar with web servers, but want to build an android application with back-end functionality, I suggest you to use something like Firebase https://firebase.google.com/ , where you can build you back-end database easy

Comment: Yeah, SQLLite doesn't work that way.  Its entire existence is to be a local database.  You either want to have a cloud based db with a webservice interface, or a syncing db like firebase, couchbase, etc.